# Remove Listener

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I've read how to do this but I'm falling short on implementation. I want an updateComplete event to run once then remove the listener.

Here's the component:

```
<mx:ComboBox 
            id="templatesCombo" 
            dataProvider="{lendersModel.fileTemplateComposites}"
            prompt="Select Template" 
            width="200" 
            labelFunction="getTemplateName"
            change="onViewTempComboChange(event)"
            updateComplete="checkTemplatesLength(event);"/>
```

Here's the handler:

```
private function checkTemplatesLength( event:FlexEvent ):void{
            if( lendersModel.fileTemplateComposites.length == 1 ){
                this.templatesCombo.selectedIndex = 1;
                this.currentFileTemplate = templatesCombo.selectedItem as FileTemplateCompositeDTO;
                this.templateActions_bb.updateButtonVisibility( 2, true  ); // disable delete button
            }
            var cb:ComboBox = ComboBox( event.currentTarget )
            cb.removeEventListener( FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, checkTemplatesLength );
        }
```

What am I missing? I thought this is how to do it from other posts I've read here.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: before and after removing event: `trace ( cb.hasEventListener ( 'updateComplete' ) )` and change to `cb.removeEventListener( 'updateComplete' ...`

Comment: When I trace it out, it says that it has the listener but for some it keeps getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it's not attached as an event listener in the first place?! but i'm sure it works this way:

```
private var cb:ComboBox;

private function init():void {
    cb = // get the right combobox
    cb.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, checkTemplatesLength);
}

private function checkTemplatesLength( event:FlexEvent ):void{
    if (lendersModel.fileTemplateComposites.length == 1 ){
        this.templatesCombo.selectedIndex = 1;
        this.currentFileTemplate = templatesCombo.selectedItem as FileTemplateCompositeDTO;
        this.templateActions_bb.updateButtonVisibility( 2, true  ); // disable delete button
    }
    cb.removeEventListener( FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, checkTemplatesLength );
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it's still not working. There must be something I'm not seeing that keeps calling the updateComplete handler.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. This does work. Seems like you have to add the listener via actionscript in order to remove it via actionscript. Thanks!